# Is there a way to evaluate logical scenarion in Elastic Search as explained below

Tags: elasticsearch

1. Hi ,I have below scenario while creating the Elastic Search
   template

   In my documents i have below fields

   doc

   ```
   field1: keyAttributes

   field2: keyValues 

   field3: others
   ```

   When user search for below scenario like

   ((keyAttributes:key1 And keyValues:value1) or (keyAttributes:key2
   AND keyValues:value2))

   The query should be able to return the documents which matches above
   criteria . Please need help , how to write this in elastic search
   template. I tried below one but not working

```json
{
  "bool": {
    "should": [
      {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match_phrase": {
                "keyAttributes": "sample"
              }
            },
            {
              "match_phrase": {
                "keyValues ": "value1"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match_phrase": {
                "contextKeys": "sample2"
              }
            },
            {
              "match_phrase": {
                "contextValues": "value2"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match_phrase": {
                "contextKeys": "sample3"
              }
            },
            {
              "match_phrase": {
                "contextValues": "value3"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Adding the sample data

document 1
"keyAttibutes":"A,B,C"
"KeyValues":"value1,value2,value3"

document 2
"keyAtrributes":"D"
"KeyValues":"Value4"

document 3
"keyAtrributes":"B,C"
"KeyValues":"Value2,Value3"

and User wants to search the data from UI like
KeyAttribute: A and KeyValues:Value1
Or
KeyAttributes: B and KeyValues:Value2

the query should return document 1 and 3

Comment: could you please add some sample data with your mapping for the index?

Comment: thanks for the reply  , Updated with the sample data

Comment: Are these fields mapped as text or a keyword?